# My USB has my stuff in it but it says it's empty

Tags: usb-flash-drive, file-recovery

My USB was working 100% fine before I went to college yesterday. I added some new files to it, took it to school, plugged it into my teacher's computer, and nothing shows up. It says it's empty. I tried it with a different computer to see if it was just the teacher's PC. I plugged it in and I got the same thing.

How do I get my files back? Most of my stuff is on there and I would like them back as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

First, open CMD. You can do this by hitting the windows key + R at the same time, then type in CMD in the box that shows up. Then in CMD, type in: cd /d [the letter for your USB drive:` (without the [ ] brackets). Example: cd /d E:

Now type the following command in CMD.

ATTRIB -S -H *.* /S /D

it might take time but would unhide all the files/folders

Comment: Do I use any spaces or just the letters themselves and together?

Comment: type the cmd as it is. with spaces

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to unhide the folders in the PC you have plugged your USB Drive to. Also try 
**Tools > Folder Options > View Tab**
 and uncheck "Hide Protected Operating System Files (Recommended)".
 Then look inside your drive. The files will most probably be there only hidden inside a hidden folder. From what you tell, it seems the said problem happened due to some virus or malware inside your teacher's PC.
 By the way, please provide further details as to whether you can see the file size in properties, etc.
Also how are you saying the content is still present on the drive. I would also suggest a full scan of the USB Drive.